# Cannot create directory in ios flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

Im using next code:

```
Directory dir = getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
Directory newDir = Directory('$dir/test');
await newDir.create();
```

and added next code in info.plist

```
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
<key>UISupportsDocumentBrowser</key>
<true/>
```

Code executing without error, but directory don't create

Update:
The code above is not correct, im using next code

```
Future<void> testFunc() async {
    Directory? saveDirectory;
    Directory tempDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
          saveDirectory = Directory('${tempDir.path}/testDir');
    
          print(saveDirectory.path);
          if (await saveDirectory.exists()) {
            print('dir exist');
          } else {
            await saveDirectory.create();
          }
}
```

Update: the path which i get: `"/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2DDAAD10-03E2-430A-84FF-58859E309C65/data/Containers/Data/Application/A90F1040-391C-4122-9DFE-EE3348310F9A/Documents/testDir"`

Comment: Are you using await inside an async function?

Comment: Yes, im using async and await

Answer (score 1):

As specified by [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider#example)'s example:

```
Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
```

The `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` is an asynchronous function. This means that if you don't put "await", the code will execute even if the function is not yet finished.

In your sample code, what's happening is that the `dir` variable hasn't been yet initialized when the code runs over it.

Update your code adding the `await`, and remember to use and `async` function.

```
Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
Directory newDir = Directory('$dir/test');
await newDir.create();
```

Comment: Im using await/async and this not helped me. May be directory created, but not showing?

Comment: What does `print(saveDirectory.path)` print?

Comment: Just for see on path

Comment: Yeah but what's the actual output?

Comment: Added path in my post

Comment: Thath's a weird path. Are you developing only for iOS devices?

Comment: That path i get from ios emulator, and develop for ios and android. On android all works fine because i using Platform check. And im using Path Provider 2.0.9